# Микропрограмма для встроенных систем на основе LIFO: определение набора инструкций микропроцессора для эффективного выполнения задачи

Tags: ассемблер, fpga

Задача на творчество и смекалку.

**Дано.** Есть память *RAM*, которая заполнена примерно так (*PA* = Physical address):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь **P** - адрес начала массива; **N** - количество элементов массива; (на **S** пока не обращаем внимание).

У *RAM* есть 2 операции:

- **READ(adr)** (возвращает значение по адресу, т.е. `val <= RAM[adr]`);
- **WRITE(adr, val)** (записывает значение по адресу, т.е. `RAM[adr] <= val`);

Также есть *стек*, в который можно класть значения на вершину и извлекать значения с вершины стека.

**Задача.** Необходимо реализовать микропрограмму (некое подобие ассемблерного кода), которая будет подсчитывать сумму элементов массива в памяти RAM, используя стек и операционные блоки, и записывать результат в **S**. Также нужно придумать свои инструкции, необходимые и достаточные для выполнения данной задачи. *(Вы можете придумывать абсолютно любые инструкции, лишь бы они могли выполняться одним простеньким операционным блоком, например, сумматором).*

**ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО!!!** Программа должна не проседать по производительности, т.е. необходимо минимизировать операции с памятью RAM.

**P.S.** Позже объявлю награду за решение задачи. Самое сложно здесь - правильно определить набор инструкций, чтобы не приходилось много раз обращаться к памяти RAM.

---

Приведу пример решения аналогичной задачи: необходимо поочередно считывать элементы массива в переменную **S**. Как это сделать? Для начала построим схему алгоритмов решения данной задачи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем определим набор инструкций (**TOS** - Top Of the Stack, указатель на вершину стека). *(Набор инструкций может иметь другую семантику и делать совершенно другие вещи со стеком)*:

- PUSHV adr - кладет переменную по адресу adr на вершину стека;
- PUSHC c - кладет константу c на вершину стека;
- WR - записывает значение, лежащее 2-ым по счету в стеке (TOS+1), в RAM по адресу, значение которого лежит на вершине стека (TOS). (затем делаем *2xPOP*);
- RD - считываем значение из RAM, находящееся по адресу, значение которого лежит на вершине стека. (перед записью значения на стек делается *POP*);
- ADD - складывает два значения, лежащие на вершине стека, и записывает результат на вершину стека;
- INC *(необязательная инструкция)* - увеличивает значение, лежащее на стеке, на 1;
- CMP - сравнивает 2 значения, лежащие на вершине стека (TOS и TOS+1) и устанавливает флаг L, если TOS < TOS+1;
- JL adr - передача управления в другое место программы (на другую строку кода по адресу adr), если L = 1;
- STOP - прекращение выполнения программы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечный результат: *(Надеюсь, нарисовал понятно. Если нужны пояснения, спрашивайте)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Меню из инструкций ограничено в 9 штук, может всётаки дать ссылку на конкретный процессор? Мне кажется задача достаточно узкая, что б её решать тут и она была интересна людям. Кроме того, можно выбирать разные модели памяти. Приведенный пример с линейным поиском - малоефективен - лучше конечно двочный поиск, но для двоичного поиска прийдется менять структуру "корня" памяти. А возможно зная больше - можно выбрать другую модель памяти вообще.

Comment: @nick_n_a я писал, что инструкции можно придумать свои. Можно сделать любую инструкцию и любое их количество. задача не привязана ни к какому процессору. Считайте, что вы сами придумываете архитектуру набора инструкций. И задача как раз в том, чтобы использовать стек (хотя логичнее здесь смотрится аккумулятор).

Comment: Для х86 программа будет выглядеть примерно так... `mov si, table; mov cx,size; @loop: lodsw; add dx,ax; loop @loop; mov ax,dx;` И? Что тут можно "улучшить"? Расчёт суммы массива ячеек можно ускорить?

Comment: @nick_n_a вы, наверно, неправильно поняли задание. У вас микропроцессор, архитектура которого позволяет выполнять универсальные задачи. у него много лишних инструкций. Здесь же задача - спроектировать свою архитектуру, которая может выполнять ТОЛЬКО ДАННУЮ ЗАДАЧУ. Нам не нужны лишние инструкции, лишние регистры. Только то, что необходимо для решения конкретной задачи.

Comment: @nick_n_a вся проблема здесь в том, как правильно организовать инструкции и программу так, чтобы можно было хранить сумму на стеке так, чтобы можно было и увеличивать указатель на элемент массива, и увеличивать сумму. Я пока не смог придумать, как это сделать без смещения указателя TOS.